# c++ vector not being found when passed to function?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

EDIT: Apparently this code is fine, but for some reason is not working on Atom's built-in c++ compiler.

So I'm trying to create a program in C++ that takes an array and then returns the average of all the numbers in that array. I've since learned that any array passed into a function "decay" into pointers, and was pointed in the direction of vectors. However, I'm stuck on this code, which doesn't seem to print out anything. I've tried debugging by having it print during the for loop, but it still doesn't print anything. Does that mean it's not finding the vector size at all, and simply ending before it starts? It's not throwing any errors, so I'm not sure. How do I get this to output the average of this vector? Thank you in advance!

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

void avg(vector<int> array){
  double total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    total += array[i];
  }
  double average = total/array.size();
  cout << average;
}

main(){
avg(arr);
}
```

Comment: Your code seems Ok to me. But it can be improved by using pass by reference, like so `void avg(vector<int>& array)`

Comment: Can confirm, your code is working fine on my computer

Comment: You need a return type for main, `int main() {}` otherwise the code works fine for me.

Comment: Other than the missing int in `int main` it should work

Comment: I get `3.5` as output, seems ok to me.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the verification everyone! It must be some version issue with Atom, I'll try to work that out!

Comment: Can confirm that it's a problem with Atom, as the code is working fine in Visual Studio. I've also added the improvements you all suggested!

Answer (score 0):

You output stream is probably buffered. Try add a newline at the end like so:

```
cout << average << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This helped, but I discovered it's probably something going wonky with Atom.

Comment: This may just be an underlying implementation difference between VS and Atom. Some more info here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl. If you were running from the command prompt though then you should have seen some output on program exit; if not then that would remain unexplained.

Answer (score 0):

```
Below code is working for me, I guess you forgot to pause the result screen

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

void avg(vector<int> array) {
  double total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    total += array[i];
  }
  double average = total / array.size();
  cout << average;
}

int main() {
  avg(arr);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I discovered it's probably something going wonky with Atom, as the code runs fine in visual studio.